# strtotime and echo'ing correct date for saturday

Tags: php, strtotime

If its Wednesday and not 10am then echo the upcoming Saturday Date.
But, if Day it Thu, Fri, Sat OR if its Wed after 10:00am then echo date or the following Saturday. I have tried to code this the best that I can, the first if statement works fine. Problem i'm having is getting the following Saturday after Wed 10:00am. How would I write that correctly?

**ex: Sun - Wed 10:00am (use upcoming Saturday), Wed 10:01am - Sat (use next weeks Saturday)**

```
if(date('D', $timestamp) == 'Wed' && date("H:i:s") <= '10:00:00') {

    echo date("m-d-y", strtotime("next Saturday")). " - Saturday"; 

}  elseif (date('D', $timestamp) == 'Wed' && date("H:i:s") > '10:00:00') {

    echo date("m-d-y", strtotime("next Saturday")). " - Saturday"; //(not this Sat one after)

}  elseif (date('D', $timestamp) == 'Thu' || 'Fri' || 'Sat') {

    echo date("m-d-y", strtotime("next Saturday")). " - Saturday"; //(not this Sat one after)
}
```

Comment: You only actually have *two* possible cases: Is it before Wednesday 10am? Then next Saturday. Else (*anything else*), Saturday next week. Or what happens on Sunday, Monday and Tuesday?

Comment: What if it is Sun, Mon, or Tues?

Comment: @deceze Correct If its before Wednesday and/or 10:00am on wednesday the it would be upcoming Saturday. If its after 10:00am on wednesday then output the following Saturday.

Comment: @MarkM If its Sun, Mon or Tues it gets the upcoming Saturday. Wed - Sat (don't use current Sat get next weeks). I've been trying to lay it out as best as I can, but was hoping another dev could clarify things a little bit more for me.

Comment: @MarkM I made a change to my question, does that help clarify things a bit more? Just need to be pointed in the right direction. Not asking for the code to be written just some suggestions to put me on the right path.

Comment: Yes, it does. Try out my answer, I think it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
if (in_array(date('D'), array('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue')) || (date('D') == 'Wed' && time() < strtotime('today 10am'))) {
    echo date('m-d-y', strtotime('saturday'));
}
else {
    echo date('m-d-y', strtotime('saturday + 7 days'));
}
```